# Header guards and redefenitions issues in c

Tags: c, header, include, header-files

I have a project with 3 files and I am quite confused as to what's the proper include order and what header guards are needed to avoid redefinition issues. 
Lets call the files a.c, a.h, b.c. b.h, c.c, c.h.
There are functions I need in all 3 of the files so I am not sure where to put them in a way it won't cause redefinition. 
a.h is the main file - and it has includes to b.h and c.h. 
b.h and c.h don't include one another. 
How to solve this? Where do I add header guards and do I add them on the entire header file or only on the section in the header files that exists in other header files that include this one? (I mean - I think I mustn't add header guards on the unique parts of the header file - that don't exist in the pother header files that include it).

Comment: do you have duplicate definitions in b.h and c.h?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Answer (score 0):

look up include guards it goes like

```
#ifndef A.H
#define A.H

"your code"

#endif
```

the name you choose for your guard does not matter.

alternative you can just use 
    #prama once

on top of your program it is widely supported.

I would say you should try to understand the hierarch y of included headers if you can. confusion is bad